# Definition of polycyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, solvable-groups

I'm trying to understand the definition of **polycyclic groups**.

A **solvable group** $G$ has two *equivalent* definitions:

1. $G$ has a **subnormal series** like $$G = H_n \rhd H_{n-1} \rhd \cdots \rhd H_0 = 1$$ s.t. each $H_{i-1}$ is normal in $H_i$ and $H_{i}/H_{i-1}$ is an abelian group for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.
2. $G$ has a **normal series** like $$G = H_n \rhd H_{n-1} \rhd \cdots \rhd H_0 = 1$$ s.t. each $H_i$ is normal in $G$ and $H_{i}/H_{i-1}$ is an abelian group for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Now [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersolvable_group) a **polycyclic group** [is a solvable group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycyclic_group) in which the factors $H_{i}/G_{i-1}$ are cyclic but there is no requirement that each $H_i$ be normal in $G$:

> In another direction, a polycyclic group must have a **normal series** with each quotient cyclic, but there is no requirement that each $H_{i}$ be normal in $G$. As every finite solvable group is polycyclic, this can be seen as one of the key differences between the definitions.

I don't understand this. If *each* $H_i$ is *not* normal in $G$ then the group $G$ doesn't even satisfy the definition of solvable groups. Furthermore, in a **normal series**, each $H_i$ is normal in $G$ *by definition* (cf. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_series#Normal_series,_subnormal_series))!

Could someone please explain what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Confusion arises because the same term **normal series** is used differently in the literature. To also quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_series#Normal_series.2C_subnormal_series)

> If in addition each $A_i$ is normal in $G$, then the series is called a **normal series,** when this term is not used for the weaker sense, or an **invariant series.**

So there are at least two schools:

1. Call the weaker case **subnormal** and the stronger case **normal** series
2. Call the weaker case **normal** and the  stronger case **invariant** series.

As a side-effect of the multi-authorship, it is perhaps not completely enforceable that Wikipedia agree upon one of the two schemes consistently (perhaps it would be best to use only *subnormal* and *invariant* and get rid of the ambiguous *normal*)

Comment: Thanks! Note that I've edited the Wikipedia article now.

Answer (score 3):

The link you provided is for supersolvable groups.  If you look over at *solvable* groups, they handle the issue of equivalence of some definitions.  Here's a link:"Solvable group - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group

If this is not the issue your having, I think the answer lies in the fact that they explicitly say that polycyclic groups are solvable.  So I don't really see what the problem is.  Afterwards they tack on some additional things, but unless you can show there's a contradiction, it's fine.